# Primes p for which the $k^{th}$ convergent of $\sqrt p$ can never be $\frac{s^2}{t^2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ be the $k^{th}$ convergent of the simple continued fraction of the prime $p$. Is it possible that $a_k = s^2$ and $b_k = t^2$ for some integers $s$ and $t$?

I have looked at $k^{th}$ convergents of $\sqrt{3}$ and noticed that this is not possible. Hence, I have come up with this observation. I wonder if it would lead to a contradiction.

Edit:

It turns out this is possible, as mentioned in the comments. So I would like to know for which primes $p$, $k^{th}$ convergent of $\sqrt p$ can never be of the form $\frac{s^2}{t^2}$?

Comment: When $k=1,$ and $b_k=1,$ this is obviously possible. E.g. $p=17,$ or $ 83.$

Comment: The second convergent to $\sqrt 5$ is $\frac 94$.

Comment: You *might* be able to prove that there are only finitely many for any prime $p.$

Comment: Also, the second convergent to $\sqrt {149}$ is $\frac {49}4$.  And the third convergent to $\sqrt {181}$ is $\frac {121}9$.  Should say, I'm only taking square roots mentally as I search here, so I probably missed cases with smaller primes.

Comment: If you could prove that for any $a,$ there are finitely many solutions to $$x^4-py^4=a,$$ then we’d get that there at most finitely many square continued fractions. That might be true even for $p$ not prime.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know enough algebraic geometry, but this seems like it should follow from Falting's theorem.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I don’t know any algebraic geometry. Okay, I tried to read Hartshorne a few times, but never got past the first three chapters or so. :)

Comment: All that requires is Thue's Theorem, chapter 22 in Mordell. Let me find a link..https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation